# Define vehicle current condition based on available latest date in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have set of vehicle information in SQL table with their **Start** date and **Failed** date.

I need to find the vehicle current condition is **Running** or not.

Example Table as follow,

| Vehicle_ID | status | date_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start | 2018-05-23 |
| 1 | Trouble | 2019-05-23 |
| 1 | Parked | 2020-06-23 |
| 1 | Start | 2021-06-15 |
| 1 | Failed | 2020-08-10 |
| 2 | Start | 2019-06-23 |
| 3 | Start | 2010-04-20 |
| 3 | Parked | 2011-04-20 |
| 3 | Failed | 2012-05-10 |
| 4 | Start | 2011-01-20 |
| 4 | Failed | 2015-01-14 |
| 4 | Start | 2016-02-25 |

Above table says,**Vehicle ID 1** latest **date_on** value is 2021-06-15 and their **status** is start, so it means Vehicle is still running.

**Vehicle ID 2** has only one record and that latest **date_on** value is 2019-06-23 and their **status** is start, so it means Vehicle is still running.

**Vehicle ID 3** latest **date_on** value is '2010-05-10' and their **status** is Failed, so it means Vehicle is stopped.

**Required Output**

| VehicleID | Running? |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 | No |
| 4 | Yes |

Note: In status column has more than 5 different state and dates but we consider only **Start** and **Failed** Status

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation with conditional logic:

```
select vehicle_id,
       (case when max(date_on) = max(case when status = 'Start' then date_on end)
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as is_running
from t
group by vehicle_id;
```

This checks if the last date for the vehicle is the last date for "Start".

Comment: your statement working fine. And also I have added status ='Start' and status ='Failed' under WHERE condition for excluding other status. many thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Vehicle_ID, case when status = 'Start' then 'YES' else 'NO' end as 'Running?'
from Yourtable y1
where date_on = ( 
                 select max(date_on) 
                 from Yourtable 
                 where Vehicle_ID = y1.Vehicle_ID  
                 group by Vehicle_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate suggestions. Now I made few changes in above example table. In that table status column has more than 5 different status and dates but we consider only Start and Failed Status to define running or not. I need you help to re modify the above your SQL statement

Comment: You can not change your question whenever you want and expect us to do your job. You have my answer and you can develop it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I made few changes on your statement, after that the statement working fine without issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below

```
with cte as
(
select Vehicle_ID,status,
row_number() over(partition by Vehicle_ID order by date_on desc) as rn
from tablename
)

select Vehicle_ID, case when status='Start' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Running
from cte 
where rn=1
```

Comment: Why not use `FETCH FIRST`?

Comment: Thanks for your immediate suggestions. Now I made few changes in above example table. In that table status column has more than 5 different status and dates but we consider only Start and Failed Status to define running or not. I need you help to re modify the above your SQL statement

Comment: @jarlh That only gets you one row, this is one row per group. If you mean `TOP 1 WITH TIES... ORDER BY rn` that is less efficient

Comment: @Charlieface, great point! (Seems like I didn't read the question carefully enough...)